# Unable to load tidycensus and map view packages on Macbook

Tags: r, package, libpq

I installed the packages `tidycensus` and `mapview` in RStudio but I get the following error when I try load either one:

```
library(tidycensus)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidycensus’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so
> Reason: image not found

```
library(mapview)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mapview’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so
> Reason: image not found

I've tried this [solution](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/83) but it is not solving my problem.

Comment: Is "tidycensus" and "mapview" packages already installed in the system.

Comment: @RaviSaroch   Yes they are. I see them installed when I select the packages tab in RStudio.

Comment: @RaviSaroch It doesn't. I see the packages in the library folder as well. The problem has to do with libpq.5.dylib. Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib Reason: image not found

Answer (score 1):

This issue indeed happened to me today when upgraded to Big Sur. After researching, finally I found a solution here:

[copy libpq.5.dylib to /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64256675/copy-libpq-5-dylib-to-usr-lib-libpq-5-dylib)

Looks like macOS is keeping libraries on `/usr/lib` closed. Basically is needed to point back `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` against another `libpq`, like the one you get by installing it with Homebrew.

This is what worked for me, first uninstall `sf` and `rgdal` packages in R and use HomeBrew to install `libpq` if needed:

```
$ brew install libpq
```

Check if library is pointing itself:

```
$ otool -l /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.0/lib/libpq.5.dylib | fgrep -A2 LC_ID_DYLIB
```

If not, point it against itself:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -id /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.0/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.0/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

And link the new path of `libpq` to each R package binary that references to it:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib [new_path] [path_to_binary]
```

In this case, for `sf` and `rgdal`:

```
$ sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.1/lib/libpq.5.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so

$ sudo install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/13.1/lib/libpq.5.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank @Cris Silva. I've been stuck with similar issues after upgrading to Big Sur when trying to load tigris package and this finally solved my problem!